# Scrapy: ImagePipline Custom File Naming

Tags: python, pipeline, scrapy

Settings.py

```
## b3 p0lit3
USER_AGENT = ' *companyname* TUTORIAL BOT - (*myemail*) | No content Generated will be used - For Educational Purpose'
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5.0
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True

BOT_NAME = 'flaticontest'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['flaticontest.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'flaticontest.spiders'
IMAGES_STORE = '/home/scriptso/Desktop/flattetstn1'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
```

items.py

```
import scrapy


class FlaticontestItem(scrapy.Item):
    images = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    pachName = scrapy.Field()
    image_name = scrapy.Field()
```

pipelines.py

```
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
class FlaticontestPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item

class CustomImageNamePipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        return [Request(x, meta={'image_name': item["image_name"]})
                for x in item.get('image_urls', [])]

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return '%s.jpg' % request.meta['image_name']
```

my spider... fltSpi.py

```
import scrapy
from flaticontest.items import FlaticontestItem

class FltspiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fltSpi"
    allowed_domains = ["flaticon.com"]
    start_urls = []

    for num in range(1,2000):
        start_urls.append("http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/" + str(num))

    def parse(self, response):
        for icon in response.css('.icon'):
            yield {
                'title': icon.css('img').re('title=\"(.*?)\"'),
                'image_urls': icon.css('img').re('set=\"(.*?) 4x'),
                'pach-name': icon.css('li').re('data-pack="(.*)\" '),
                'image_name': icon.css('img').re('title=\"(.*?)\"'),
            }
```

Having a hard time understanding the logic behind pipe-lining in general but can you spot what im doint wrong here? Im almsot positive the issue is somewhere in the pipeline (obviously)... anyone care to point me to the right direction?!

---

### Update Edit

Some More troubleshooting this is where I am at the moment.

settings.py

```
USER_AGENT = 'BASH.SEC TUTORIAL BOT - (bash.sec@multuslegio.net) | No content Generated will be used -Educational Purpose'
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5.0
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
BOT_NAME = 'flaticontest'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['flaticontest.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'flaticontest.spiders'
IMAGES_STORE = '/home/scriptso/Desktop/flattetstn1'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'flaticontest.pipelines.CustomImageNamePipeline': 1}
```

pipelines.py

```
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.http import Request


class FlaticontestPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item

class CustomImageNamePipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
            return [Request(x, meta={'image_name': item["title"]})
                    for x in item.get('image_urls', [])]

    def get_images(self, response, request, info):
        for key, image, buf, in super(CustomImageNamePipeline, self).get_images(response, request, info):
            if re.compile('^[0-9,a-f]+.jpg$').match(key):
                key = self.change_filename(key, response)
            yield key, image, buf

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return '%s.jpg'% request.meta['image_name']
```

items.py

```
import scrapy


class FlaticontestItem(scrapy.Item):
    images = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    pachName = scrapy.Field()
    image_name = scrapy.Field()
```

{{spyder}}.py

```
import scrapy
from flaticontest.items import FlaticontestItem
from flaticontest.pipelines import *

class FltspiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fltSpi"
    allowed_domains = ["flaticon.com"]
    start_urls = []

    for num in range(1,2000):
        start_urls.append("http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/" + str(num))

    def parse(self, response):
        for icon in response.css('.icon'):
            yield {
                'title': icon.css('img').re('title=\"(.*?)\"'),
                'image_urls': icon.css('img').re('set=\"(.*?) 4x'),
                'pach-name': icon.css('li').re('data-pack="(.*)\" '),
                'image_name': icon.css('img').re('title=\"(.*?)\"'),
            }
```

I feel like Im getting closer .... bececause not the output is showing this...

> 2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/54>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/54>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/52>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/52>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/52>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/52>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/52>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/52>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/52>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/52>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/50>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/50>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/50>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/50>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/50>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/50>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/48>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/48>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/48>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/48>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/48>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/48>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/48>
>   None
>   2017-01-20 12:48:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/computing_23394/48>
>   None

from the looks of it, its recursively going through each item (output only showing the page response but obvious that it is).. but even though that im not getting my items returned for a some reason I've yet to troubleshoot, I do believe my pipeline set up should be goo to rename the the downloaded images...

Comment: Looks like there is some code misformatting for pipelines.py so please clarify whether you overload `process_item` method for your images pipeline? If so, then you should not do that because it breaks pipeline.

Comment: Hey there! yeah woops!  The first process_item its commented out... just typo'd... all still remains as stated...